# Split string where it contains a character into an array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have several characters (~) within a sentence. On every ~, I want to split the text before that into an array item. Every array item then needs a `<br />` tag at the end.

I tried using replace but it was only working for the first ~ and ignoring the rest. Which is why I think splitting into an array maybe more beneficial down the line.

```
$("h2").html(function(index, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.replaceAll('~', '<br />');
});
```

Example:

This is some text~This is some text underneath that text~some more text here~and a final bit of text

```
<strong>This is some text</strong><br />
This is some text underneath that text<br />
some more text here<br />
<strong>and a final bit of text</strong>
```

Comment: `return currentHtml.split('~').join('<br>')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use split with join

```
$("h2").html(function(index, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.split('~').join('<br />');
});
```

or change it to a regex

```
$("h2").html(function(index, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.replace(/~/g,'<br/>'); // g signifying global
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. It just occurred to me that I also need to bold specific paragraphs. Any way of achieving that with the current setup?

Comment: will probably need more specifics - can you show a snippet of the text maybe.. and tell me which parts need the bolding

Comment: Updated my OP with an example at the bottom. Thanks btw